# How to print array elements into string without string function

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Hi so I wanted to put array elements to become a string. The objective is I wanted to put the string in print function.
For instance:

Given an array of [1, 2, 0, 1]
Is there any way to make the elements to become one string (i.e. to be 1201)?
Lets say the string variable is '''array_elements'''
I want to have the output of:

> the elements are: 1201.

So of course what I should do to the print function is:

```
print("the elements are: " + str(array_elements), ".")
```

The problem is, I'm a python beginner and i don't know how to solve the problem without using string function (since this is what google told me to do, but I'm now allowed to use that." What I could think of is by using looping but I still can't manage to make it as one string variable

Comment: you don't have to use `str` function, just `print(...)` or use [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/). If you want to join list elements, use `''.join(your_list)` and make sure the list contains strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
"".join(str(x) for x in [1, 2, 0, 1])
```

You need to convert integers to string, since you want to have a string in the end. this is what happens under the hood anyway

However if you actually want an integer this is another task. Then you can do this:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda a, b: 10 * a + b, [1, 2, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to print the elements one by one in a loop, using the `end=""` argument to avoid ending the line before you're ready:

```
print("the elements are:", end=" ")

for x in [1, 2, 0, 1]:
  print(x, end="")

print()
```

Comment: oh my god, why did I not think of this. This will work so well with the looping method of my own. Thank you so much